# Closing a CMD Window after launching an application through command line from Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I am trying to do the following. It works but the cmd window waits for the acrobat.exe to finish executing before exiting. I have to use this method of launching because I intend to pass certain command line parameters in future.

```
cmdLineString := Format('/c ""%s" "%s""',['C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe', 'F:\Android-interview\Packt.Android.3.0.Application.Development.Cookbook.Jul.2011.ISBN.1849512949.pdf']);
ShellExecute(Handle, 'open', 'cmd.exe', PChar(CmdLineString), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a number of ways to improve this:

1. Don't use `ShellExecute`. It is tempting to do so because it is simple to call. However, it is not very flexible. Use `CreateProcess` instead.
2. If you must hide a console window, pass the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW` flag to `CreateProcess`.
3. That said, there is no point to use `cmd` here. You don't need to create a process that creates another process. Doing so actually makes it harder to pass on arguments. Create the Acrobat process directly. Cut out the middle man.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by David and after following a few other questions regarding `CreateProcess` the solution code finally looks as shown below. Putting here for other beginners like me. Just think about what all things are possible with this piece of code! Thank you, Delphi.

```
procedure TForm.btnCMDLaunchClick(Sender: TObject);
var
   commandLine: string;
   si: TStartupInfo;
   pi: TProcessInformation;
begin
   commandLine := Format('%s %s',['C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 11.0\Acrobat\Acrobat.exe', 'F:\Android-interview\Packt.Android.3.0.Application.Development.Cookbook.Jul.2011.ISBN.1849512949.pdf']);
   UniqueString(commandLine);
   si := Default(TStartupInfo);
   si.cb := sizeof(si);

      if CreateProcess(
        PChar(nil),         //no module name (use command line)
        PChar(commandLine), //Command Line
        nil,                //Process handle not inheritable
        nil,                //Thread handle not inheritable
        False,              //Don't inherit handles
        0,                  //No creation flags
        nil,                //Use parent's environment block
        PChar(nil),         //Use parent's starting directory
        si,                 //Startup Info
        pi                  //Process Info
      ) then begin
       CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
       CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
      end;
end;
```

Comment: This code doesn't check for errors and leaks two handles.

Comment: si, pi need to be freeandnil in the end and fileexist errors?

Comment: No. You need to check the return value for error, and if successful pass the process and thread handles to CloseHandle. It's explained in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, that's it now.